# Error using POSIXlt in R: Character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, datetime, error-handling, posixlt

I am attempting the run the following line of code in R:

```
    as.POSIXlt(c("28/7/2022  17:56:20", "28/3/2021  1:10:41 PM"), tryFormats = c("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%OS %p",
                                                               "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%OS"), optional = F)
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
    Error in as.POSIXlt.character(c("28/7/2022  17:56:20", "28/3/2021  1:10:41 PM"),  : 
      character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I've already ran this code on a similar vector of time/dates where it worked with no issues. The code also works when I run it on each of the date/time strings individually. The error only occurs when I try to convert both these strings at the same time.

**Update:** Following the guidance from Ritchie in the comments, I've found a similar Daylight savings time issue which suggested setting the tz = "UTC".
This resolved the error I was getting but now "28/3/2021  1:10:41 PM" is being converted to "2021-03-28  01:10:41" rather than "2021-03-28  13:10:41".

Note: This conversion works fine when the tz parameter isn't set

Comment: Probably a daylight saving time issue - what's your timezone?  DST began on March 28 2021 in many European countries.

Comment: My timezone is in Ireland which changed to GMT+1 on the 28th March in 2021. Would you have a suggestion on how this can be resolved?

Comment: That worked Ritchie, thanks a million!